# Does a create-react-app project only load / import from files in the src folder?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-check-updates

I have been trying to optimize the dependencies in my project so I installed npm-check. And it brought to my attention that the files outside of the src folder such as the scripts, server and webpack files have imports that do not exist in the package.json.

Does this mean that they are installing these packages only to be used during the build creation? Do these packages not live on the production build?

How do I update these packages used in these files if they are not controlled by the package.json?

Appreciate the help

Comment: Can you give an example of such an import?

Comment: Yeah, here are some examples:
express
autoprefixer